# How to update data in database using Struts2 and Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jsp, struts2

Hi I'm working in updating data in database by using Struts2 and hibernate. I have the difficulty in getting the Id in the url, would please help me?

These are my codes:

#### updateUser.jsp

```
<s:form action="updateList" method="POST">
   <s:submit value="Update User"/>
</s:form>
<s:iterator value="contactList" var="contacts">
 <s:property value="firstName"/>&emsp;<s:property value="lastName"/>
&emsp;<a href="updateHere.jsp?id=<s:property value="id"</s:property>">Update</a><br/>
</s:iterator>
```

And when I click the link Update. This is what i see. I wanted to get the id there.

```
http://localhost:8080/BiddingStrutsEx/updateHere.jsp?id=3
```

#### updateHere.jsp

```
<s:actionerror />
<s:form action="updateU" method="POST">
<s:hidden value="%{id}" name="id"/>
<s:textfield name="contacts.firstName" label="First Name"/>
<s:textfield name="contacts.lastName" label="Last Name"/>
<s:select label="Company" headerValue="Select Your Company"
list="{'Aboitiz Equity Ventures','Aboitz Power','Aboitiz Land'}" name="contacts.company" value="Aboitiz Equity Ventures"/>
<s:select label="Department"
list="{'Computer Service Department','INFRA'}" name="contacts.department" value="Computer Service Department"/>

<s:textfield label="Enter Your Username" name="contacts.username"/>
<s:password label="Enter Your Password" name="contacts.password"/>
<s:textfield label="Enter Your Email" name="contacts.email"/>
<s:checkbox name="contacts.notify" label="Do you want to notify you if someone gets higher bid than your bid?" fieldValue="true"/>
<s:radio label="What kind are you?" name="contacts.kindOfPerson" list="#{'1':'Buyer','2':'Seller','3':'Both'}" value="1"/>
<s:submit value="Update"/>
</s:form>
```

#### struts.xml

```
<action name="updateU" class="net.viralpatel.contact.view.RegistrationAction" method="updateUserEx">
    <result name="success">/updateUser.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">/updateHere.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">/updateHere.jsp</result>
</action>
```

#### RegistrationAction.java

assume that I already declared the Id and others.

```
public String updateUserEx() {
if(this.getId().equals(null)) {
    addActionError("Fill All!");
    return ERROR;
} else {
    try {
        contacts.setId(this.getId());
        contactManager.updateUserEx(contacts);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        addActionError("Error brad!");
        return ERROR;
    }
    this.contactList = contactManager.getListContacts();
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

#### ContactManager.java

```
public Contacts updateUserEx(Contacts contactsList) {
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
session.beginTransaction();
Contacts contacts = (Contacts) session.get(Contacts.class, contactsList.getId());
contacts.setFirstName(contactsList.getFirstName());
contacts.setLastName(contactsList.getLastName());
contacts.setEmail(contactsList.getEmail());
contacts.setCompany(contactsList.getCompany());
contacts.setDepartment(contactsList.getDepartment());
contacts.setUsername(contactsList.getUsername());
contacts.setPassword(contactsList.getPasswords());
contacts.setNotify(contactsList.isNotify());
contacts.setKindOfPerson(contactsList.getKindOfPerson());
session.update(contacts);
session.getTransaction().commit();
return contacts;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't call JSP directly. Instead create an action that returns that JSP. In the action bean create a property `id` to hold parameter value populated by Struts.

```
<action name="updateHere" class="net.viralpatel.contact.view.RegistrationAction" method="updateHere">
  <result>updateHere.jsp</result>
</action>
```

In the action class

```
private String id;
//public getter and setter

public String updateHere(){
  return Aciton.SUCCESS;
}
```

In the JSP you can use Struts anchor tag.

```
<s:property value="firstName"/>&emsp;<s:property value="lastName"/>&emsp;<s:a action="updateHere"><s:param name="id" value="%{id}"/>Update</s:a><br/>
```

The URL in the href attribute is generated from the action mapping, something like this

```
/BiddingStrutsEx/updateHere.action?id=3
```